# Concat scss files via @import or via build tool

Tags: webpack, sass, gulp, gruntjs

I know to different ways to concat/combine scss files.

1. each one via a task runner e.g. in `gulp` (this should be similar in `grunt` or `webpack`)

   ```
   // gulpfile.js
   gulp.src([
       "./assets/scss/var.scss",
       "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
       "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
       "./assets/scss/frontend/nav.scss",
       "./assets/scss/frontend/footer.scss"
   ])
   ```
2. each one via `@import` in a scss file:

   ```
   // assets/scss/frontend.scss
   @import 'var.scss'
   @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
   @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome"
   @import 'frontend/nav'
   @import 'frontend/footer'

   // gulpfile.js
   gulp.src("./assets/scss/frontend.scss")
   ```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the two ways?

Answer (score 1):

**1st example:** imagine that you have a stylesheet (`utils.scss`) that both `nav.scss` and `footer.scss` depend on. If you will pass only one file to gulp then import directives will be resolved and styles will be imported in the correct order. On the other hand, if you will pass multiple files to gulp you need to manage files' order yourself.

**2nd example:** imagine that only `footer.scss` depends on `utils.scss`. For some reason, you decide to remove footer styles from the gulp build. If you added `utils.scss` with SASS `@import` directive, it will be excluded from the build automatically but if you passed all your styles to Gulp than you need to remove `footer.scss` and `utils.scss` manually.

So I think that the second approach with the `@import` directive is much better.